# How is the Ethereum merge counter-timer calculated?

Tags: the-merge

[image]

How are these estimates calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through terminal total difficulty!

The merge happens when the difficulty reached certain stage which is called **merge difficulty**.

And **the time** takes to reach the merge difficulty from the current difficulty is how they estimate the time.

As for how it is calculated, you can find it [here](https://github.com/taxmeifyoucan/predict_ttd/).

You have the answer you are looking for in the image you have shared.

Tell me if it helps!